# disable button if cell value is > 0 google spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Can someone help me with the following code (thanks to LennyZ71)
I am trying to enable a button when the value of cell G2 is empty else show error message and hide the button.

```
  function doGet() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('Key');
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('member');
  var member = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow()-1, 1).getValues();
  Logger.log(member)


  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('Check In');
  var grid = app.createFlexTable().setId('grid');
  app.add(grid);

  var row = 0;
  var column = 0;

  for (var m in klant) {    

    grid.setWidget(row, 0, app.createLabel(member[m]));

//----------- if value of cell G2 is empty the enable the button below else show error message  -----------\\

    grid.setWidget(row, 1, app.createButton('Check In').setId(row+2).addClickHandler(app.createServerHandler('checkIn').addCallbackElement(grid)).addClickHandler(app.createClientHandler().forEventSource().setEnabled(false)));}
    row++;
  }
  return app;
}

function checkIn(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('Key');
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('member');

  var button = e.parameter.source;

  sheet.getRange(button, 7).setValue(new Date());
  sheet.getRange(button, 8).setValue(Session.getActiveUser());    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try simply like this:

(the error message will come right under the button but you could also place it on its right by adjusting its coordinates in the table

Note : you said "enabled" and "hide", you'll have to choose one or the other... to hide it use `setVisible(true/false)` instead of `setEnabled(true/false)`

```
function doGet() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('Key');
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('member');
  var member = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow()-1, 1).getValues();
  Logger.log(member)


  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('Check In');
  var grid = app.createFlexTable().setId('grid');
  app.add(grid);

  var row = 0;
  var column = 0;
  var enable=false;
  for (var m in klant) {    

    grid.setWidget(row, 0, app.createLabel(member[m]));

//----------- if value of cell G2 is empty then enable the button below else show error message  -----------\\
    if(sheet.getRange('G2').getValue() ==''){enable=true}
    grid.setWidget(row, 1, app.createButton('Check In').setEnabled(enable).setId(row+2).addClickHandler(app.createServerHandler('checkIn').addCallbackElement(grid)).addClickHandler(app.createClientHandler().forEventSource().setEnabled(false)));}
    row++;
    if(!enable){
      grid.setWidget(row, 1, app.createHTML('<b>error</b> message'));
      row++;
    }
  }
  return app;
}
```

Comment: is it possible to replace the button with the message?

Comment: i am trying this but it doesn't work
if(sheet.getRange('G2')==''){
      grid.setWidget(row, 1, app.createButton('Check In').setId(row+2).addClickHandler(app.createServerHandler('checkIn').addCallbackElement(grid)).addClickHandler(app.createClientHandler().forEventSource().setEnabled(false)));}
    else {  grid.setWidget(row, 1, app.createHTML('<b>error</b> message')); }

Comment: Thanks i fixed it you forgot to put .getvalue in the code
so it has to be like this:  if(sheet.getRange('G2').getValue()==''){enable=true}